# Build/Install MapServer on own Server

Tags: mapserver

Is it possible to **build** or **install MapServer** on your own server? If yes, is there a documentation that could help me on how to do it or how it goes, or anyone that could tell me how. I have installed MapServer on my Windows and was able to run it on my localhost, but I want it to be online and transferred it to a hosted server.

I would really appreciate if you could help me with this matter. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes MapServer can be built from source on your own server, or you can use an existing installer package on that server.

Regarding building yourself, there are several documents to follow on the MapServer website [here](https://mapserver.org/installation/index.html).

If you want to use an installer package, it depends on what operating system you want to deploy MapServer on.  If Windows: you can use [MS4W](https://ms4w.com/) (MapServer for Windows), which is a very popular installer that includes everything you need, in a simple .zip file (I am the longtime developer behind both MS4W and the company that maintains it, GatewayGeo).

If you want to deploy on a Linux server, it depends on the Linux flavor, for example Ubuntu is a popular flavor and you can use the [UbuntuGIS package](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGIS) to install MapServer.

I try to keep all of these options well documented on the MapServer website [here](https://mapserver.org/download.html#binaries), for Mac/Linux/Win, but if you notice another option missing please let me know.

Also, if you are looking to pay for a hosted MapServer installation, there was a [wiki page](https://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/wiki/HostingProviders), on the former wiki, but please note that this information is likely a decade old.

Hopefully some of these notes gives you some guidance.

And thanks for using MapServer.

-jeff mckenna